# Value relation autocompletion and dropdown menu in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, widget

I use a value relation widget which is connected to a list of streets.

If I tick "use completer" I can use the autocompletion but the dropdown menu disappear. The dropdown menu appears again only if I type a first letter.

I would like to have both autocompletion and dropdown menu even when no  letter is entered because sometimes the surveyor doesn't know by heart the spelling of a street.

Is it already possible or under development ?

I am using QGIS version 2.18.13

Here is a screenshot with widget properties - the function "use completer" is thicked

[image]

Here is the menu without completer

[image]

Here is the menu with completer (I have to type at least one letter to let the dropdown menu appear)

[image]

Comment: Can you put your code sample for better help?

Comment: Hi Francisco. I edited the post to be clearer.